# Como usar minimum_should_match buscando por mais de um campo?

Tags: elasticsearch

Estou tentando filtrar o meu resultado do elasticsearch onde deve ser retornado os resultados onde forem 80% compatível com o texto buscado.

Quando eu utilizo apenas uma coluna a regra do `minimum_should_match` funciona perfeitamente:

```
{
   "size":30,
   "from":930,
   "query":{
      "filtered":{
         "query":{
            "query_string":{
               "default_field":"campo1",
               "query":"portugues",                  
               "minimum_should_match":"80%"
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Quando busco por mais de um campo não importa o valor que eu coloque em `minimum_should_match` que a mesma quantidade de resultados sempre é retornada:

```
{
   "size":30,
   "from":123420,
   "query":{
      "filtered":{
         "query":{
            "query_string":{
               "default_operator":"or",
               "query":"portugues",
               "fields":[
                  "campo1",
                  "campo2^5",
                  "campo3"
               ],
               "minimum_should_match":"80%"
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Pelo que estou verificando provavelmente eu tenho que inserir um `minimum_should_match` para cada coluna ou algo assim.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tive que usar o `bool` e `multi_match`, essa é a forma certa:

```
{
   "size":"30",
   "from":0,
   "query":{
      "filtered":{
         "query":{
            "bool":{
               "should":[
                  {
                     "multi_match":{
                        "query":"portugues",
                        "type":"cross_fields",
                        "fields":[
                           "campo1^3",
                           "campo2^5",
                           "campo3^3"
                        ],
                        "minimum_should_match":"80%"
                     }
                  }
               ]
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```